# Excel formula to count cells that contain specif text

Tags: excel-formula

I have the list of month names in "column R" and from columns "S:AU" I have random data.
In this range, i have region names in some cells. I am trying to count by month the number of cells named with a particular region.

It appears that i am missing something simple. This is my current formula:

=COUNTIFS(R:R,"jan",S:AU,"=APAC")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COUNTIFS() requires the ranges to be the same size, so you will need to either string together a lot of individual COUNTIFS and sum:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(R:R,"jan",S:S,"=APAC"),COUNTIFS(R:R,"jan",T:T,"=APAC")...
```

OR you will need to limit the references to the data set and use an array type formula like SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($R1:INDEX(R:R,MATCH("zzz",R:R))="jan")*($S1:INDEX(AU:AU,MATCH("zzz",R:R))="APAC"))
```